# Upload photo using MVC 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

I want to upload photo and save in database by using **Asp.Net MVC 4** (Framework must be 4.5) ? I see several web tutorial and video but can't get actual answer. In this problem user can choose multiple photo from device also. **My model class is**

```
 public class Picture
 {
    [Key]
    public int PictureId { set; get; }
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { set; get; }
 }

  **My Controller is**


  namespace Picture_Rpload.Controllers
  {
  public class PictureController : Controller
  {
    private PictureDbContext db = new PictureDbContext();

    //
    // GET: /Picture/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Pictures.ToList());
    }

    //
    // GET: /Picture/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        Picture picture = db.Pictures.Find(id);
        if (picture == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(picture);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Picture/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Picture/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    //public ActionResult Create(Picture picture)
    //{
    //    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    //    {
    //        db.Pictures.Add(picture);
    //        db.SaveChanges();
    //        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    //    }

    //    return View(picture);
    // }

    public ActionResult Index(Picture picture)
    {
        foreach (var file in picture.Files)
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/images"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    //
    // GET: /Picture/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        Picture picture = db.Pictures.Find(id);
        if (picture == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(picture);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Picture/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Picture picture)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(picture).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(picture);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Picture/Delete/5

    public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
    {
        Picture picture = db.Pictures.Find(id);
        if (picture == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(picture);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Picture/Delete/5

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Picture picture = db.Pictures.Find(id);
        db.Pictures.Remove(picture);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be help this several links

- [Multiple File Upload MVC C#](http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2013/03/multiple-file-upload-mvc-c.html)
- [Ajax Multiple File Upload Script With Progress Bar, Drag And Drop Qq.FileUploader In Mvc 4 Razor](http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2012/09/ajax-multiple-file-upload-script-with.html)
- [How To Create EditorFor FileUpload In Asp.Net Mvc 4 Razor?](http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2013/05/how-to-create-and-editorfor-fileupload.html)

Comment: Thanks..the first link is works in my project..
Multiple File Upload MVC C#  :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple input type="file" on the client will do the trick. On your controller you receive the file(s) in a model/variable of type HttpPostedFileBase, make sure your form has a content type of multiform/part-data (forgot the exact name)